# How to get event from inside a custom plugin fired from the outside without passing it as an argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I am making a JQuery plugin that needs to know the the context event that called the plugin so I can do `e.preventDefault();` from inside.

The plugin is here: https://github.com/brenosilver/JQuery.PopupBox

Currently I have this:

```
    $("#el").click(function(event){
        $("#targetEl").popupBox(event);
    });
```

But I don't want the event to be passed as I'm trying to make it as user friendly as possible.

Inside the plugin I have this:

```
    $.fn.popupBox = function(event, options){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

---

I had success using:

```
var contextObject = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer.parentNode;  
var event = $._data( $(contextObject)[0], "events" );
```

but this doesn't return a native event type object. So I can't use `event.preventDefault();`.

---

Further explanation:

I need to have `event.stopPropagation` because if not, the element the plugin handles just shows on the screen then hides instantly.

Comment: According to your plugin usage, it's not its job to `e.preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`. Plugin should not care about this.

Comment: But the whole purpose of the plugin is to make an element popup in the middle of the screen when something is clicked. If I don't have event.stopPropagation() the element will just show then hide instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and the example of the plugin usage, it's seems to me that the design of the plugin should be a little different.

Plugin should not be concerned with outside-world events, and of course it should not mess with events and whatever happens outside of it. After all this is the purpose of the plugin - to be plugged in and operate.

I recommend to change the strategy to the one where you bind click events on the click target *inside* of the plugin.

The configuration then might look like this:

```
$("#targetEl").popupBox({
    clickOn: '#el'
});
```

or other way around:

```
$("#el").popupBox({
    target: "#targetEl"
});
```

In both cases you would bind click event inside of the plugin yourself and be able to do with event whatever you need.

Comment: I had thought of doing that at first, but then I decided to let the user call the plugin on any event he desires. On top of that, passing event seems much easier than passing {target: "#targetEl"}, but as you mentioned it might not be a good design decision.

Comment: I have redesigned the plugin to your recommendation, but instead i'm using two separate arguments, one for the target element and one for the options `.popupBox($("#targetEl"), {options})`. Thank you, this was my first JQuery plugin btw.